# Divisible 4 for every different number?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, recursive-algorithms

My formula is for ABC 3 digits number;

100A + x*B + y*C.

What should coefficient of B and C be for everytime different result for different number?

(Result number ) mod 4 has to be zero.

For example: 
for x=44 and y=4 ;

my formula is 100A + 44B + 4C 
So;

and for example Result number is := 724.

Now I m searching to 724 from 100. But I see five numbers that provide the 724.
Numbers:

397 -> 724

474 -> 724

551 -> 724

629 -> 724

706 -> 724

But ı want to only one number that provide to 724. What should coefficient of B and C for One result? I have two rıules that:

1- Result number must be divisibility to 4. ex: 100 104 108 112 116 888 808 900 444 etc..

2- Every result number must give me different number. In my example five numbers give me the same result. but I want to only one number give me one result.

How can I solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Is there anybody here?